# Semantic UI progress bar reset

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I was trying to use the Semantic UI progress bar as a vote/poll graph.
When I tried resetting the data-value to zero, the progress bar would not animate and change back to zero.

```
$('#choiceA').progress({value:0, total:0});
```

It seems like setting value to some extremely small number makes the animation work though:

```
$('#choiceA').progress({value:0.00000001, total:0});
```

Is this an acceptable fix to the problem? Or is there a better way to do this.

edit: seems like the issue has been brought up here https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1395

Answer (score 1):

Set progress percent 0:

```
$('#choiceA').progress({
  percent: 0
});
```

or use

```
$('#choiceA').progress('reset');
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/jh5vaaf5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('.ui.progress').progress('reset');
```

taken from [here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/f4e8e490f6cc4de4761823a2e06c8563903e6ff7/src/definitions/modules/progress.js) to reset the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

try setting percent to 0

```
$('.ui.progress.black').progress({percent: 0});
```